# Javascript merging of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array myData of the following form

```
"myData": [{
    "items": [{
        "attr1": "someInfoBatch1",
        "attr2": "someOtherInfoBatch1"
    }],
    "someStates": [ "STATE_PASS_1" ]
},{
    "items": [{
        "attr1": "someInfoBatch2",
        "attr2": "someOtherInfoBatch2"
    }],
    "someStates": [ "STATE_PASS_1", "STATE_FAILED_1" ]
}]
```

Now I want to merge `myData.items` based on values in `someStates`

So if someStates contains pass in one batch & failed in other batch (i.e. say `STATE_FAILED_1`), I want `myData.items` to be separate (i.e. `myData.item[0]` & `myData.item[1]`)

But let's say if in the above example someStates contains only passed states as below; For first batch `"someStates":["STATE_PASS_1"]`
& for 2nd batch `"someStates":["STATE_PASS_1", "STATE_PASS_2"]`

In the above case, I need to merge myData.items into a single array as below;

```
"items": [{
    "attr1": "someInfoBatch1",
    "attr2": "someOtherInfoBatch1"
},{
    "attr1": "someInfoBatch2",
    "attr2": "someOtherInfoBatch2"
}]
```

Comment: Not sure how exactly these two rows are different in your example. To follow you description: in general, just write your own mapper for `myData`, checking each subsequent object `someStates` value with `.some((statePassFlag) => { /^STATE_FAILED/.test(statePassFlag)})`

Comment: But is it possible to merge the 2 arrays ?

Comment: Of course: `[].push.apply(onearr, anotherarr)`. But what you show here is not _merge_ per se.

Answer (score 0):

can do with underscore in one line like: `_.pluck(myData, "items")`

see http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

Comment: Could you add a little explanation?

Answer (score 0):

decomposed undescore.js:

```
  // Return the results of applying the iteratee to each element.
  var map = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    iteratee = cb(iteratee, context);
    var keys = !isArrayLike(obj) && _.keys(obj),
        length = (keys || obj).length,
        results = Array(length);
    for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
      var currentKey = keys ? keys[index] : index;
      results[index] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);
    }
    return results;
  };

  var property = function(key) {
    return function(obj) {
      return obj == null ? void 0 : obj[key];
    };
  };
```

and the call: `var items = map(myData, property("items"));`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for it.

```js
var $scope = { "myData": [{ "items": [{ "attr1": "someInfoBatch1", "attr2": "someOtherInfoBatch1" }], "someStates": ["STATE_PASS_1"] }, { "items": [{ "attr1": "someInfoBatch2", "attr2": "someOtherInfoBatch2" }], "someStates": ["STATE_PASS_1", "STATE_FAILED_1"] }] },
    items = $scope.myData.map(function (a) {
        return a.items[0];
    });

console.log(items);
```

ES6

```js
var $scope = { "myData": [{ "items": [{ "attr1": "someInfoBatch1", "attr2": "someOtherInfoBatch1" }], "someStates": ["STATE_PASS_1"] }, { "items": [{ "attr1": "someInfoBatch2", "attr2": "someOtherInfoBatch2" }], "someStates": ["STATE_PASS_1", "STATE_FAILED_1"] }] },
    items = $scope.myData.map(a => a.items[0]);

console.log(items);
```